# Drag and Drop in .Net c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have implemented a list that i want to be able to order using drag and drop.

I have implemented the list using the ajaxToolkit ReorderList.

It works perfectly on the user interface the problem i am having is related to the update of the data into the database.

I created a button that allows the user to save the changes (all at once), the problem is that in the click event if I loop troughs the ReorderList the items are returned in the original order, not the one as the user have modified it. Seems like despite the list is re-orderd the ReorderList maintains the original datasource.

this is my list

```
<ajaxToolkit:ReorderList ID="rlVerticalMenu" runat="server" DragHandleAlignment="Left"
          ItemInsertLocation="Beginning" DataKeyField="Id" SortOrderField="Priority"
          EnableViewState="true" OnItemReorder="rlWorkItems_ItemReorder" 
          CallbackCssStyle="ClsCallBackStyle" CssClass="ClsReorderListContainer">          
        <ItemTemplate>                
            <div class="ClsItemArea">
               <div>                    
                    <asp:Label ID="LblId" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="editable_textarea" Text='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() %>' />
                    <div class="verticalMenuItem">
                        <asp:Label ID="LblDisplayName" runat="server" CssClass="editable_textarea" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName").ToString() %>' />
                    </div>
                    <div class="verticalMenuItem">                        
                        <asp:Label ID="LblHref" runat="server" CssClass="editable_textarea" Text='<%# Eval("Href").ToString() %>'/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="verticalMenuItem">                        
                        <asp:Label ID="LblTooltip" runat="server" CssClass="editable_textarea" Text='<%# Eval("Tooltip").ToString() %>'/>
                    </div>
               </div>                                               
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ReorderTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="ClsReorderCue">
            </asp:Panel>
        </ReorderTemplate>
        <DragHandleTemplate>
            <div class="ClsDragHandle">
            </div>
        </DragHandleTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:ReorderList>                       
   <asp:Button ID="BtnGenerateMenu" runat="server" Text="Generate Menu" OnClick="BtnGenerateMenu_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Any idea how I should implement this?
How do I implement the

```
protected void rlWorkItems_ItemReorder(object sender, ReorderListItemReorderEventArgs e)
        {


        }
```

method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement a sorting algorithm, i am not sure if there is a better way to do this but it works

```
protected void rlWorkItems_ItemReorder(object sender, ReorderListItemReorderEventArgs e)
    {

        List<VerticalMenuItem> list = (List<VerticalMenuItem>)Session["VerticalMenuItems"];
        List<VerticalMenuItem> newList = new List<VerticalMenuItem>();

        //if move one place - no matter top or bottom
        if (e.NewIndex - e.OldIndex == 1 || e.OldIndex - e.NewIndex == 1)
        {
            VerticalMenuItem oldItem = list[e.OldIndex];
            VerticalMenuItem newItem = list[e.NewIndex];
            list[e.NewIndex] = oldItem;
            list[e.OldIndex] = newItem;
            Session["VerticalMenuItems"] = list;
            return;
        }
        //From bottom to top
        if (e.OldIndex - e.NewIndex > 0)
        {
            VerticalMenuItem oldItem = list[e.OldIndex];                
            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewIndex; i++)
            {
                newList.Add(list[i]);
            }
            list.Remove(oldItem);
            newList.Add(oldItem);
            for (int i = e.NewIndex; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                newList.Add(list[i]);
            }
            Session["VerticalMenuItems"] = newList;
            return;
        }
        //From top to bottom
        if (e.OldIndex - e.NewIndex < 0)
        {
            VerticalMenuItem oldItem = list[e.OldIndex];
            list.Remove(oldItem);
            for (int i = 0; i < e.NewIndex; i++)
            {
                newList.Add(list[i]);
            }                
            newList.Add(oldItem);
            for (int i = e.NewIndex; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                newList.Add(list[i]);
            }
            Session["VerticalMenuItems"] = newList;
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you reordering the list using `OrderBy`, which is a LINQ expression that enumerates the list in an ordered fashion, or by `Sort`, which actually changes the order of the list?

You might choose to iterate through the list in the click event using `OrderBy` like so:

```
var qry = MyList.OrderBy(item => item.OrderingProperty)
```

In this way, if you loop through `qry`, you will have a list ordered by the property you specified in your LINQ lambda expression.